# Adding images to an array memory issue

Tags: iphone, memory, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm currently facing the following issue:

My app dynamically creates images (320 x 480 pixels) and adds them to a NSMutableArray. I need those images inside that array in order to allow users to browse through them back and forth. I only need to keep the latest 5 images. So I wrote a method like below:

```
- (void)addImageToArray:(UIImage*)theImage {
    if ([myMutableArray count] < 5) {
        [myMutableArray addObject:theImage];
    }
    else {
        [myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [myMutableArray addObject:theImage];
    }
}
```

This method basically does what it's supposed to do. However, in instruments I can see, that memory usage is permanently incrementing. At some point, even though I do not have any memory leaks, the app finally crashes. 
The way I see it, XCode does remove the image from my array, but does not release it. Is there a way I can make sure, that the object I want to remove from my array will also get released? Maybe my approach is completely wrong and I need to find a different way.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

[EDIT:]

As requested, I'm adding part of my code, which creates the image:

```
-(UIImage*)getGL {
unsigned char buffer[320*480*4];
glReadPixels(0,0,320,480,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&buffer);

CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, &buffer, 320*480*4, NULL);
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(320,480,8,32,320*4,CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,ref,NULL,true,kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

size_t width         = CGImageGetWidth(iref);
size_t height        = CGImageGetHeight(iref);
size_t length        = width*height*4;
uint32_t *pixels     = (uint32_t *)malloc(length);
CGContextRef _context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGContextTranslateCTM(_context, 0.0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(_context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(_context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), iref);
CGImageRef outputRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(_context);
UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputRef];


CGDataProviderRelease(ref);
CGImageRelease(iref);
CGImageRelease(outputRef);
CGContextRelease(_context);

return outputImage;
}
```

So, now I can do something like this:

```
[self addImageToArray:[self getGL]];
```

Hope, this helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you *disabled* NSZombie?

Comment: The problem may lie with the way you initialize theImage. Include that section of your code in your question too.

Comment: I don't remember enabling it in the first place. Is it switched on by default?

Comment: @Friendly: No. But check the Arguments tab in the executable info.

Comment: @Friendly. Your code looks fine. The crashes may be related to something else in your code.

Comment: That's strange. As I said, no memory leaks detected in instruments. However, whenever my method gets called memory usage incements by 0.7 to 1.0 MB. I tried to switch off adding images to the array and memory usage did no longer increment. Weird, isn't it? That kinda tells me, it must be the way I'm adding and removing objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, problem found - problem solved :)

Actually my getGL method was missing something:

```
free(pixels);
```

That didn't cause any memory leaks, but incrementing memory instead. Now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons that the memory isn't being freed.

One is that you're adding all the images in a loop and the autorelease pool isn't releasing autoreleased objects until control gets back to the run loop. You might want to create and release a NSAutoreleasePool for each time through the loop.

Another is that the objects aren't being properly released. Use "Build and Analyze" to find any obvious memory leaks.